# Select element having biggest number

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery I am able to loop through each div's HTML and determine which one has the greatest number, like this:

```js
var biggestNum = 0;
$('div').each(function(){
    var currentNum = parseInt($(this).html());
    if(currentNum > biggestNum) {
        biggestNum = currentNum;
    }
});

alert(biggestNum);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>5</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>3</div>
```

How can I then select the containing div of the biggest number and do stuff to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach is use a descending `sort()` on the jQuery collection of elements and target the first after sorting. This has no impact on positioning in the dom

```js
$('div').sort(function(a,b){
    return $(b).text() - $(a).text();
}).first().css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>5</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: Much simpler and easier to work with than my solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution myself by using a function. Working snippet:

```js
var biggestNum = 0;
$('div').each(function(){
    var currentNum = parseInt($(this).html());
    if(currentNum > biggestNum) {
        biggestNum = currentNum;
    }
});

alert(biggestNum);

$('div').filter(function() {
  var num = +($(this).text().trim());
  return num >= biggestNum;
}).addClass('green');
```

```css
.green {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>5</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>3</div>
```